# Bit.ly like shortcode algorithm

Tags: php, url-shortener

I'm trying to make a url shortener for a client. I've got a decent algorithm going right now, the only problem is that if the client was to shorten the same URL for a different promotion it would create the same code.

What can I do to prevent that?

```
$hash = sha1($this->data[$this->alias]['us_url']);
$this->data[$this->alias]['shortid'] = base_convert(hexdec($hash), 10, 32);
```

I'd like to be able to create multiple shortcodes for the same url to track it differently.

Comment: Pretty sure the codes these sites use are just random.  They are linked in a database to their respective sites.

Comment: Without changing your algorithm much, you could salt the hash with a shorten-ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same procedure as when creating password hashes: Use some salt.

```
$hash = sha1($randomly_generated_salt . $my_url);
```

Thus, same input strings will create different hashes.
The salt should have a decent length to provide enough entropy.

(Although you wouldn't use sha1 to hash passwords!)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would you use to hash passwords?

Comment: bcrypt or an algo with a similar strength. Check your fav search engine for further information on why and how to use bcrypt (execution time, future-proof, bruteforce-proof, rainbow table-proof if properly used).

Answer (score 0):

Add the possibility to give a custom url. In pseudocode:

```
if(isset($customUrl) && isUniqueLabel($customUrl)) {
    createCustomUrl()
} else {
   createUsualUrl()
}
```

Given the custom URL the client has the possibility to define the url manually (as is.gd and many other services are doing) and this will increase the possibility of customization.

Comment: I do have that already available and working with dupe checks.